Consolidate table values into Pivot table using a table list as the reference to worksheets
I have a 'Shopping list' of items that I want consolidated into a Pivot Table. The catch is making the range dynamic. The range should only pull data from worksheets referenced in the worksheet "Cocktail Conversion Sheet" which has 2 tables, 'Table 48' & 'Table 49'. I've entered worksheets 'Bee's Knees', 'Between the Sheets' & 'Bijou' as an example, these will need to be amended.
Much Appreciated

Sub ShoppingList()

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:= _
    Array(Array("'Bee''s Knees'!R3C2:R14C8", "Item1"), Array("Bellini!R3C2:R14C8", _
    "Item2"), Array("'Between the Sheets'!R3C2:R14C8", "Item3"), Array( _
    "Bijou!R3C2:R14C8", "Item4")), Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
    :="'[Classics.xlsm]Shopping List'!R4C2", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
    DefaultVersion:=8
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
    "Count of Value").Position = 1

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Column")
    .PivotItems("BATCHABLE" & Chr(10) & "Y/N").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("COG" & Chr(10) & "JUG").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("COG" & Chr(10) & "SINGLE").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("SHARE" & Chr(10) & "SERVE (MLS)").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("SINGLE" & Chr(10) & "SERVE (MLS/GMS)").Visible = False
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Count of Value")
    .Caption = "Sum of Value"
    .Function = xlSum
End With

End Sub

Blockquote

ShoppingList
Cocktail Conversion Sheet
